# problem metric involving sequences

Tags: functional-analysis

> UPDATED: In preparation for an exam I am struggling with the following problem. We have $A:=\{x=(x_{n})_{n}\in \ell^{2}| \phantom{x} \|x\|\leq 1\}$. Consider the metric $d:A\times A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ defined by 
>   $$d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/3)^{n}|x_{n}-y_{n}|.$$
>   Prove that $(A,d)$ is sequentially compact.

What I have done so far:
I have updated what I have done so far using the hints below. But I still have some questions as I want to make sure I understand it thorougly.

Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ be an arbitrarily chosen sequence in $A$. Now first take a subsequence $(x_{n1})_{n}$ such that the first component converges. Now take a subsequence of this subsequence $(x_{n2})_{n}$ such that the second component converges. 
Going on in the same way we get a sequence of nested subsequences $(x_{n(k+1)})_{n}\subset (x_{nk})_{n}$. Now take the sequence $(x_{kk})_{k}$, this construction guarantees that every component of this sequence converges, it is equivalent to the convergence in the metric. Also note that for each $k,n$ that $x_{nk}$ is a sequence of real numbers so we have in fact three layers of sequences. Since the elements are sequences and we take sequences of these elements and than a sequence of subsequences of the sequence of elements in $A$. Hence, $(A,d)$ is sequentially compact.

(Question: Have I now formally proved that indeed $(A,d)$ is sequentially compact)

I don't have much experience with these kind of proofs so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Made updates using the hints below.

Comment: You need to use an indexed subscript to keep track of the various subsequences to get it totally right. Something like this: The first subsequence is given by indices $n_{j1}$ so that $x_{n_{j1}}1$ converges as $j\to\infty$. The next one will be given by $n_{j2}$ being a subsequence of $(n_{j1})$ so that $x_{n_{j2}2}$ converges, and so forth. You may prefer to write $y_{jk}=x_{n_{jk}k}$ instead, so that $(y_{j(k+1)})_j$ is a subsequence of $(y_{jk})_j$, then take the diagonal $y_{jj}$. This awful mess is the reason I wrote the note I refer to in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

(**Note:** The question was substantially altered since I wrote this answer. If you wish to see what I *really* answered, use the history mechanism to see the original question.)

You got it wrong from the start. Let's drop the comma and just write $x_n=(x_{nj})_j$, shall we? Now you want convergence in the first component, so you'd like to have $x_{n1}$ convergent as $n\to\infty$. It won't be convergent necessarily, but you can pick a subsequence that converges. Note that this really means picking a subsequence of $(x_n)$ so that $(x_{n1})$ converges. Next, pick a subsequence of the subsequence so that $(x_{n2})$ converges, and so on. Finally, “take the diagonal” to finish the proof.

Incidentally, I think the conventional notation for subsequences is a horrible mess, and makes this kind of proof much harder than necessary, both to write and to read. So I have written up an [alternative view of the diagonal method](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hanche/notes/diagonal/). The basic idea: All the difficulties stem from the insistence of relabeling indices when taking a subsequence, so that the sequence is always indexed on the set of natural numbers. By allowing subsets of the natural numbers as index sets, we simplify this tremendeously.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have updated my question using your hints and I want to make sure that I understand it thoroughly so if you could give me feedback if I have now really finished the proof I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Much better. Unfortunately, I don't have time for a detailed reading right now. I think you have the right idea, but your notation at the end still seems somewhat deficient. (It is *notoriously* hard to get right, so don't feel bad about it.) I'll add a comment to the question with a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you. I look forward to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show something that's bounded with respect to the $d$ metric has a convergent subsequence, not that something that's bounded with respect to the normal $l^2$ norm has a convergent subsequence.